# Oracle SQL: Select first date for list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I will try to explain this the best that I can.

I have a requirement where I need to pull in the very first letter sent date for a case.

```
Case     |   Letter_Sent_Date
1234     |   05/29/2012
1234     |   05/30/2012
1234     |   06/01/2012
```

How can I build an oracle sql where the below 'WHERE' condition would EXLUDE this case from appearing on the report?

```
WHERE Letter_Sent_Date between '01JUN2012' and '30JUN2012'
```

Since the very first letter sent was not in June, I do not want it to appear on this report and to only appear when I run the report for May.

Comment: What would you like to show up on the May report vs. the June report? First letter in May and nothing in June?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the MIN window/analytic function for this:

```
select case_id, letter_sent_date
from (select case_id, letter_sent_date,
             min(letter_sent_date) over (partition by case_id) as mindate
      from t
     ) t
where mindate between '01JUN2012' and '30JUN2012'
```

This eliminates all cases based on when the first letter was sent.  If you just want the row eliminated, then AriStorm answered that.

Comment: +1. This makes more sense than the other analytic functions like rank.

Comment: @RajeshChamarthi, the problem, and the benefit, of `rank()` is that is't more "difficult" to use. The difference is that when using the PK only you _always_ know when you have the correct answer.

Comment: correct. But in most cases, you would also need to select the rest of the columns in the row. (say you also need to pick up the letter_subject and address in the above case). In that case rank/row_number is probably the choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first letters in one query and then write a where on top of it to filter based on the date range.

To get the case and the first letter..

```
select case_id,
       letter_sent_date
  from (
    select case_id,
           letter_sent_date,
           rank () over (partition by case_id order by letter_sent_date asc) rnk
      from case_table
       )
  where rnk = 1
```

To get only the cases where the first letter was sent in the dates  you specified..

```
select case_id,
      letter_sent_date
 from (
    select case_id,
           letter_sent_date,
           rank () over (partition by case_id order by letter_sent_date asc) rnk
      from case_table
      )
 where rnk = 1
   and letter_sent_date between to_date('01-JUN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY) 
                            and to_date('30-JUN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you are looking for:

```
select case, letter_sent_date {, and any other fields you want from the table}
from table_name
where letter_sent_date between '01-jun-2012' and '30-jun-2012'
```

This will then output

```
case  |  letter_date_sent
1234  |  06/01/2012
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, please clarify your request :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  What I am needing is to only populate the first Letter_Date_Sent for the case.  So if the letter_date_sent has multiple values across many months, I do not want this Case to populate on those following months.  The issue comes when we specify the reporting period based off 'letter_sent_date' in the 'WHERE' statement.  since it only looks at if there are any 'letter_date_sent' values for that specific month, it will populate that case for each reporting month.  I am looking to only have the case appear for the month the very first letter was sent out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or the old school GROUP/HAVING:

```
 SELECT case_id, MIN(letter_sent_date)
   FROM case_table
  GROUP BY case_id
 HAVING MIN(letter_sent_date) BETWEEN '01-JUN-2012' and '30-JUN-2012'
```